# Mysql query seems mixed up

Tags: mysql

```
$q=2013

$sql="SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'vecka' and date >= '"$q ."-01-01' and date <= '"$q ."-01-31' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$janw = mysql_num_rows($result);

$sql="SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'manad' and date >= '"$q ."-01-01' and date <= '"$q ."-01-31' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$janm = mysql_num_rows($result);

$sql="SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'ar' and date >= '"$q ."-01-01' and date <= '"$q ."-01-31' ";
```

This line '"$q ."-01-01' is it = "2013-01-01" ?

My program that i uses to build the code with says there is an error but i cant find any errors i tested this in my PHPadmin

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'ar' and date >= '2013-01-01' and date <= '2013-01-31' ";
```

And it works fine. I just want to make sure this is the correct line to use.
Cuse when i tested

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'ar' and date >= '"2013 ."-01-01' and date <= '"2013 ."-01-31' ";
```

It dident work. I might be mixing up ' and ".

Thanks for all help

Comment: If this is your exact code you're missing a `;` after `$q=2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'vecka' and date >= '".$q."-01-01' and date <= '".$q."-01-31'";
```

It will give you the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'vecka' and date >= '2013-01-01' and date <= '2013-01-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think ya need another dot. When you concatenate, you should have a period between any string and any variable. Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
"SELECT * FROM vip_sales WHERE type = 'manad' and date >= '" . $q ."-01-01' and date <= '" . $q ."-01-31' ";
```